# SQLiteException SQLite error near "@Param1" syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008, sqlite

I've got an SQLite table that I created for a new project.

The table's **CREATE** and **INSERT** commands are defined as follows:

```
public const string SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE Tanks " +
  "(LocID INTEGER, InUse INTEGER, Text1 TEXT, Description1 TEXT);";

public const string SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO Tanks " +
  "(LocID, InUse, Text1, Description1) " +
  "VALUES " +
  "@LocID, @InUse, @Text, @Description); ";
```

Whenever I attempt to save my first values to the table, I get the unhelpful message, "*SQLite error near "@LocID" syntax error*."

Here is my insert routine:

```
public static Tank New(Tank tank) {
  tank.Result = 0;
  using (SQLiteConnection con = GetConnection) {
    try {
      con.Open();
      using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Tank.SQL_INSERT, con)) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocID", tank.LocationID); // = 1
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InUse", tank.InUse); // = 1 (for true)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text", tank.Text); // says "New Tank"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", DBNull.Value); // I've tried "New Tank" and DBNull.Value
        try {
          tank.Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (SQLiteException err) {
          tank.Result = -1;
          LogError("New(Tank)", err);
          throw err;
        }
      }
    } finally {
      con.Close();
    }
  }
  return tank;
}
```

I did not create the database with the index and I am not inserting an index value because the documentation says: "*every row of every table has an 64-bit signed integer ROWID. The ROWID for each row is unique among all rows in the same table.*" A little further down in the same page, it says, "*If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.*" Source: [sqlite.org/autoinc](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

The error is thrown on `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

What have I done wrong?

Using SQLite 3 in Win7 Visual Studio 2008 (C#), targeting Windows Mobile 5 (Pocket PC).

Comment: For starters look at your Insert statement after Values.. shouldn't there be Values(, , , ) what ever param values you are passing..? please show what Tank's structure is as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the opening parenthesis before @LocID in the SQL_INSERT string.

```
public const string SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO Tanks " +
  "(LocID, InUse, Text1, Description1) " +
  "VALUES " +
  "(@LocID, @InUse, @Text, @Description); ";
```

Comment: Man I hate Noobie mistakes like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your missing a `(`. Do this instead:

```
public const string SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO Tanks " +
"(LocID, InUse, Text1, Description1) " +
"VALUES " +
"(@LocID, @InUse, @Text, @Description); ";
```

Comment: Crap, crap, crap! I can't believe I struggled that long on that problem.